# Passing Func to Linq to Entities Sum(..)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am trying to create a method which I group an entity on a couple of fields and then get the some of another field. Like so:

```
    private async Task<List<KpiGrounping<int>>> GetGrouping(IQueryable<MyEntityType> query, Func<MyEntityType, int> selector)
    {
        return await (from item in entity
              group itemby new
              {
                  item.DimCountry.Geo,
                  item.DimPlatform.Platform
              } into x
              select new MyGrounpingDto
              {
                  Geo = x.Key.Geo.Trim(),
                  Platform = x.Key.Platform.Trim(),
                  Value = x.Sum(selector)
              }).ToListAsync();
}
```

which I call like  `var foo = GetGrouping(context.MyEntities, x=>x.MyValue);`

When i do this i get the error: "Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025." thrown - which i can make little sense of.

I also find that if i dont pass in the selector, and instead directly call sum, like `Value = x.Sum(s => s.MyValue);` then it works fine

Comment: Change the `selector` parameter type to `Expression<Func<MyEntityType, int>>`

Comment: Then i get the error that the item 'x' doesnt contain a definition for 'Sum'.

Calling x.AsQueryable().Sum(selector) then works. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to do that like this:

```
private async Task<List<KpiGrounping<int>>> GetGrouping(IQueryable<MyEntityType> query, Expression<Func<MyEntityType, int>> selector)
    {
        return await (from item in entity
              group itemby new
              {
                  Geo = item.DimCountry.Geo.Trim(),
                  Platform = item.DimPlatform.Platform.Trim()
              } into x
              select new MyGrounpingDto
              {
                  Geo = x.Key.Geo,
                  Platform = x.Key.Platform,
                  Value = x.Sum(selector)
              }).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Yes, as @Yacoub Massad suggested too. But I have to change the value assignment to: x.AsQueryable().Sum(selector)